# vb.net how I get a list of active and open forms in MDIparent inside MenuStrip Horizontally?

Tags: vb.net, forms, mdichild, mdiparent

Please, How I get a similar Open And Active child forms that are located in the "Windows" ToostripMenuItem in MdiParent as the picture below. but I want them horizontally, is there anyway to that? I appreciate your help.
[image]

**UPDATE: SOLUTION**
I figured out a way to do what I want, and here is the solution
first this code is to add a ToolStripMenuItem to the mdiparent on form_load

```
  Me.MdiParent = MDIParent1
    mdf.BackColor = Color.Red
    mdf.Text = Me.Text
    AddHandler mdf.Click, AddressOf mdf1_Click
    MDIParent1.MenuStrip.Items.Add(mdf)
```

then the ToolStripMenuItem click handler on the form

```
Private mdf As New ToolStripMenuItem
Private Sub mdf1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Me.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

and this code is to remove the ToolStripMenuItem when the form is closed in (Form_formclosing) event

```
Try
        Dim ParentForm As MDIParent1 = MDIParent1
        Dim OptionsMenuStrip As MenuStrip = ParentForm.Controls("MenuStrip")
        Dim Items As ToolStripItemCollection = OptionsMenuStrip.Items
        Dim removeThese As New List(Of ToolStripMenuItem)
        For Each Item As ToolStripMenuItem In Items
            If Item.Text = Me.Text Then
                removeThese.Add(Item)
            End If
        Next
        For Each item In removeThese
            Items.Remove(item)
            item.Dispose()
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
```

and to set the back color to red of the ToolStripMenuItem of the active form in MdiParent_MdiChilActivate event

```
Private Sub MDIParent1_MdiChildActivate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.MdiChildActivate
    Try
        Dim activeChild As Form = Me.ActiveMdiChild
        Dim ParentForm As MDIParent1 = Me
        Dim OptionsMenuStrip As MenuStrip = ParentForm.Controls("MenuStrip")
        Dim Items As ToolStripItemCollection = OptionsMenuStrip.Items
        For Each Item As ToolStripMenuItem In Items
            If Item.Text = activeChild.Text Then
                Item.BackColor = Color.Red
            Else
                Item.BackColor = Color.LightGray
            End If
        Next
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub
```

and the result: (The active form is the red ToolStripMenuItem):

[image]

Comment: Of course there's a way to do that, but you have to do it yourself. There's no automatic way to do it. You need to go to the `MdiChildren` collection of the parent form and then create a menu item for each one yourself. Before you ask, no I won't be providing code for that. It's up to you to make an attempt and then post if and when you encounter a specific issue.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, check out the update. thanks anyway.